# Problem with UICustomSwitch,

Tags: ios4

I am using UICsutomSwitch for my application. When I try to create it, I am getting an exception like,

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'

My code is as follows,

UICustomSwitch.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


 @interface UICustomSwitch : UISwitch 
{
}
-(void)setLeftLabelText:(NSString *)labelText;
-(void)setRightLabelText:(NSString *)labelText;
@end
```

UICustomSwich.m

```
 #import "UICustomSwitch.h"


 @implementation UICustomSwitch
 -(UIView *)slider
 {
  return [[self subviews ] lastObject];
 }
-(UIView *)textHolder
{
  return [[[self slider] subviews]objectAtIndex:2];
 }
-(UILabel *)leftLabel
 {
   return [[[self textHolder] subviews]objectAtIndex:0];

  }
-(UILabel *)rightLabel
{
  return [[[self textHolder] subviews]objectAtIndex:1];

}
-(void)setLeftLabelText:(NSString *)labelText;
{
   [[self leftLabel] setText:labelText];
 }
-(void)setRightLabelText:(NSString *)labelText
{
   [[self rightLabel]setText:labelText];

}
@end
```

View Controller:

```
     UICustomSwitch* switchView=[[[UICustomSwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,5,90,30)]autorelease];
    [switchView setLeftLabelText:@"F"];
    [switchView setRightLabelText:@"M"];
    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(genderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [elementView addSubview:switchView];
```

I am getting exception at  " return [[[self slider] subviews]objectAtIndex:2];"  call. I don't know what is the wrong, Can you guys please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Sekhar.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: I'm having same issue too!! Someone help! dun be useless stranger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across this issue and found the answer here:[Custom UISwitch Text](http://codefortravel.com/blog/custom-uiswitch-text/)

Basically in iOS 4, there were UILabel's in the UISwitch's subviews that represented the "On/Off" labels. In iOS 5, there are no UILabels in the subviews array (hence the array error you're getting). The above link offers an external class you can download and customize. In my opinion, it seems like Apple is discouraging customization of UISwitch. The functionality you're after could be accomplished another way (segmented control, simulated checkbox, etc).

Also, in the given link above, the author proposes that the issue might be with not including armv6. I tried this and it does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The exception indicates you are attempting to access an element of the array that is out of bounds (in a place that is larger than the actual size of the array).

You can use breakpoints and/or NSLog() calls carefully placed in your code to determine if this array ever is not-empty, and if that is so, you can continue to use these calls to find out just where the array becomes empty.

Clearly if the array is empty then the switch is setup differently than you expect it to be.